# Create custom user login for xpages

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

Does anyone know if it is possible to create a login in XPages / Domino, where one can create their own users who are not on the Domino server.

I need to create a database that has users connected to a customer.

Customer further orders that they want to see. There can be several hundred customers eventually.

The reason I want to create a separate database for users is that users will have different rights and fields than those found in Lotus names.nsf

Comment: It's been a long time since I checked the terms of IBM's license for Domino, so I'm not sure what the current offerings are, but in the past certain license models that charged based on the number of authenticated users were worded in a way that any authentication at all, even authentication without having an actual account on the server, was counted and could require payment to IBM. There were other license models available that did not charge per user. I would strongly recommend that you check into your specific rights under the licenses that you've purchased.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a separate NAB and add it via Domino's Directory Assistance to the server.
This allows you to create the external users from the other company in this NAB only and won't affect your companies *names.nsf*.

The external users would have their own company hierarchy, something like

```
*/Acme/US
```

f.e.

```
Mary Jane/Acme/US
```

The can login with the default Domino mechanism (including the password change mechanism etc). And you can use the other features of Domino like Groups, ACLs etc.

The users would log on to your site with their email adress, that's why there is no be  problems with "doubled users" (*Hans Mueller/Acme/US* and *Hans Mueller/YourCompany/US*).

The DA must only run on the Webserver that the external users should access. You don't have to replicate it all around in your infrastructure.

**EDIT:**

You can create user documents in this external NAB without any problems. I prefer a self-registration with a email validation mechanism (to prevent the use of an internal email adress, f.e. of *Hans.Mueller@YourCompany.com*).

The users can choose their own password. All you have to do is to create a new Person document in the NAB and do a *Compute with Form* (this sets the HTTP password).
If a user wants to change the password, you can use the *?ChangePassword* functionality. And if a user forgets his password, an agent creates a new one in the person document and sends it via mail to the user email address.